# Директива self

Tags: foundation, objective-c, xcode

Изучаю Objective-C по книге Stephen Kochan.
Понял, что директива self используется в случае, когда мы вызываем, например, метод внутри метода, чтобы обозначить, что сообщение мы отправляет обрабатываемому экземпляру класса.
Но в книге есть вот такой пример:

```
-(void) setName:(NSString *)theName andlastName:(NSString *)theLastName andEmail:(NSString *)theEmail
{
 self.name = theName;
 self.lastname = theLastName;
 self.email = theEmail;
 NSLog(@"set: %@ %@ %@", name, lastname, email);
}
```

Кто знает, зачем здесь используется директива self и имеет ли она вообще какой-то вес в данном примере?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

self это всегда указатель на то чему принадлежит метод - объекту (как тут) или классу (если речь идет о методах класса, которые с + начинаются). Он примерно соответствует this в С++

Конкретно тут self используются для доступа к свойствам объекта. В принципе, можно и без него, но тогда нужно писать _name, _lastname  и т.п. (строго говоря, вы можете обозвать ивары -поля как угодно, но если не указано ничего другого, компилятор сгенерит именно такие поля и сеттеры-геттеры к ним)